# Precise reference for the equivalence of $E_n$ algebras and locally constant factorization algebra?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, infinity-categories

I've seen the following theorem attributed to Lurie:

> Theorem. There is an equivalence of $(\infty,1)$-categories between $E_n$ algebras and locally constant factorization algebra on $\mathbf{R}^n$.

And the reference is usually given as Lurie's Higher Algebra. However it's a 1500+ pages book and search for "factorization algebra" doesn't have a match.

Can anyone give me a pointer to where exactly this is proved in Higher Algebra, or in some other books? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The result in question is a corollary to proposition 5.4.5.15 in Higher Algebra

> **Theorem 5.4.5.9.** Let $M$ be a manifold and let $C^⊗$ be an $∞$-operad. Composition with the map
>   $$\mathrm{Disk}(M)^⊗ → \mathbb{E}_M^⊗$$
>   of Remark 5.4.5.8 induces a fully faithful embedding
>   $$θ:\mathrm{Alg}_{\mathbb{E}_M}(C) → \mathrm{Alg}_{\mathrm{Disk}(M)}(C)\,.$$
>   The essential image of $θ$ is the full subcategory of $\mathrm{Alg}_{\mathrm{Disk}(M)}(C)$ spanned by the locally constant $\mathrm{Disk}(M)^⊗$-algebra objects of $C$.

When $M=\mathbb{R}^n$, the $\infty$-operad $\mathbb{E}_M$  is just the $\mathbb{E}_n$-operad.

Be careful that the book does not use the language of factorization algebras, but if you compare the definitions you'll see that there is a conservative functor from locally constant factorization algebras on $M$ to locally constant $\mathrm{Disk}(M)$-algebras such that the functor in theorem 5.4.5.9 factors as
$$\mathrm{Alg}_{\mathbb{E}_M}(C)→\mathrm{Fact}^{lc}_M(C)→\mathrm{Alg}_{\mathrm{Disk}(M)}(C)$$
where the middle term is the $\infty$-category of locally constant factorization algebras and the first arrow is the one given by taking factorization homology. This, plus the existence of the "global sections" functor $\mathrm{Fact}^{lc}_M(C)→\mathrm{Alg}_{\mathbb{E}_M}(C)$ is enough to conclude the result you're after.

Comment: @h__ Embarrassingly I cited the wrong result (in the right section) in the first version of this answer. Please, be sure to check the reference again if you missed the edit. Sorry about it!

Comment: I saw your correction. No problem. Thank you again.

Comment: Surely HA.5.5.4.10 is also relevant here, unless "factorization algebra" means something different than "factorizable cosheaf on the ran space".

Comment: @DylanWilson It means the same thing, but that is a theorem, not a definition. See for example [these notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.5213), in particular section 4.1. The whole chapter 5 is of course relevant, but I was trying to keep it short :)